# Is it always true that virtual function cannot be inlined in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction

It is said that virtual functions cannot be inlined. Is it always true that if a function is declared virtual, it cannot be inlined anywhere in the code, or is it applicable only under certain situations? (eg., calling method from a base pointer vs. calling method on a reference, etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, virtual functions can indeed be inlined. Virtual dispatch is only used when calling a virtual method polymorphically (i.e., on a pointer or reference to an object). However, when a virtual method is called on an object *value*, virtual dispatch is not used and the compiler is free to inline as it sees fit.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as a "class value". Perhaps "object value" could work. :)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal : Fair enough.

Answer (score 6):

Given:

```
struct T {
   virtual void foo() { /* something */ }
};
```

**Using polymorphism** (*If you're calling `foo()` through a `pointer-to-T` or a `reference-to-T`*)

```
T* ptr = get_ptr_somehow();
ptr->foo();
```

If a compiler *knows* that `T` is the only node in its inheritance tree, it could forego the virtual calls and potentially inline the function. However, this is an incredibly unlikely scenario and I doubt whether it could even feasibly be detected. In all other cases, inlining is not practical due to the run-time dispatch.

**Static dispatch** (*If you're calling `foo()` on a bog-standard object*)

```
T obj;
obj.foo();
```

In this case, the compiler knows that the dynamic type of `obj` is `T`, that it does not require virtual dispatch, and therefore may inline the function code if it wants to.

```
T* ptr = get_ptr_somehow();
ptr->T::foo();
```

In this case, the compiler doesn't know the dynamic type of `obj`, but it knows which function it's going to call, knows that it does not require virtual dispatch, and therefore may inline the function code if it wants to.

Comment: Or, if you have `T x; x.foo();`, the call to `foo()` can be dispatched statically since the dynamic type of `x` is known to be `T`.

Comment: @James: Yup, good point. Have edited to incorporate this scenario.

Comment: For completeness, dynamic dispatch can be disabled by a direct call even through a pointer: `base * p = get_pointer(); p->base::foo();` that call is fully static and will be resolved by the compiler and potentially inlined.

Comment: @David: Indeed. I'll add that for completeness. :)

Answer (score 3):

A virtual member function is basically a pointer to a function that points to the correct function to call depending on the class hierarchy implementations. (note that it don't have to be a pointer, but it's often implemented as this because it seems to be the most efficient implementation for this abstraction).

That suggest that knowing wich function will be called is only determined at runtime.

So how would it be possible to inline a function that is only known at runtime? Impossible.

> Unless you have a JIT compiler :) –
>   the_drow

True. Not common and you might loose some performance on boot, but still true.

Comment: Unless you have a JIT compiler :)

Comment: Oh yeah, sure. I'll add that :D

Answer (score 2):

Objects declared on the stack or inside classes, for example, do not need dynamic dispatch on their virtual functions which are called, because the compiler knows for a fact the types of all objects on the stack, so basically any value. Virtual function dispatch only occurs through pointers or references.

Answer (score 1):

When optimizations are concerned, very little is always true. In general, if the compiler can not tell what the actual type of an object is, virtual functions have to be resolved at runtime. If you have an actual instance (Class versus Class&) then the compiler can be sure. If you have a reference, it will have to guess; if the calling function is itself inlined, it might identify the static type that way or it might not.

Note that in this case, there is no difference between a pointer and a reference. In either case, you get runtime polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual functions (methods) can be inlined.  Remember that the `inline` keyword is a suggestion to the compiler, not a requirement.

Inlining code is much like pasting the function, as-is, where needed in the executable.  A standalone function is not created.

When there are pointers to an inline function (internally by the compiler or externally by the programmer), the inlining may not be used.  There must be one instance of an inlined function when there are pointers to it.  The compiler is free to inline the code, but there must be one instance at a static (fixed) location to satisfy the pointers.

My suggestion is to inline simple, less than 5 lines of code, methods without using a profiler.  Remember that inlining is usually placing code in a header file.  When the method's code is changed, all translation units depending on the header file must be rebuilt.  This could be costly in big systems.  Generally, big chunks of code should only be inlined **after** they are validated **and only to improve efficiency as dictated by the profiler.**